# how to make a grid so that the borders go beyond the columns in CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a design of cards with border above columns
[image]
how to make a grid so that the borders go beyond the columns with CSS?

Comment: Center the card content in flex or grid and use padding/margin/gap?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this design. it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to use pseudoelements on each item to simulate borders. The benefit to this approach is that you don't need to add any extra HTML elements just for styling purposes.

However, the downside is that at some screen widths you might see the lines appear slightly thicker due to subpixel rendering.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

li::after,
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% + 50px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

li::after {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #e6e6e6;
  left: -1px;
  top: 0px;
}

li::before {
  bottom: -1px;
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px 0px #e6e6e6;
  left: 0;
}

li:nth-child(6)::before,
li:nth-child(12)::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0px 0px #e6e6e6;
}

li:first-child::after,
li:nth-child(7)::after {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>       
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>       
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
     <li>Content</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

solution using extra table rows on top and bottom with `.extend` cells and only showing the `border-right` on them:

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.extend{
  border:unset;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  height:30px;
}
td{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-left:transparent;
}
.right{
  border-right:transparent;
}
```

```html
<table class='table' >
  <tr>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class='right'></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class='right'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
    <td class='extend'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```